# Vagrant - Generate an ssh key and output it

Tags: ruby, vagrant, ssh-keygen

I would like to generate an ssh-key during my vagrant provisioning, and output the public key to the user.

Obviously I can easily create an ssh key using something like

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<SCRIPT
  yes | ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
SCRIPT
```

How can I then take /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub and give it to the user running Vagrant?

Or, is there a way to generate it in ruby, put the private key into the VM and give the public key to the user?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a dumb solution, so if anyone can think of a better one, I'd be really grateful:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<SCRIPT
  yes | ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
  echo
  echo *********************************
  echo * PUBLIC KEY - PUT ME ON GITLAB *
  echo *********************************
  echo
  cat /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
  echo
SCRIPT
```

A friend also suggested copying the key to `/vargrant` which is the folder which is usually mounted from the host folder containing the relevant Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<SCRIPT
  yes | ssh-keygen -b 2048 -t rsa -f /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa -q -N ""
  cp /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /vagrant
SCRIPT
```